# How to add forgot pasword rest server api in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, forgot-password

I am working on app which uses drupal 7.x rest server api.
I have service like login, logout
For Ex.

```
http://sample.com/xyz/xyz_drupal/rest/user/login
POST :
username:user
password:pwd

http://sample.com/xyz/xyz_drupal/rest/user/logout
```

Now, 
I want to create forgot password api but i am new on drupal and no idea about how patch works or add new service like regular drupal service.
Please help me.

```
http://sample.com/xyz/xyz_drupal/rest/user/reset_password
Params will be:
email: xyz@yahoo.com
```

Please help me where to start.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should take a look at [**`this`**](https://www.drupal.org/node/1303400). Services module allows to make Forgot password request.

- **Request type:** `POST`
- **Resource:** `?q=rest/user/request_new_password.json`
- **Send name or email:** `foo` or `foo@bar.com`

Note: You may have to change Resource a bit to suit your project.